# Why does Environ not set the variable in a Django project root other than the main?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

So I have a .env file in my Django project root containing several variables.

When I use them within the same project root (e.g. in settings.py) it works, but once I try to access a variable within another root/module it fails:

```
# other root than .env
import environ

# Initialise environment variables
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Get the iCloud application password via env
mail_password = env('MAIL_PW')

# --> returns django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the MAIL_PW environment variable
```

This however works:

```
# same root as .env
import os
import environ

# Initialise environment variables
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code fails, because `environ.Env.read_env` cannot find the `.env` file.

Here the source

```
    @classmethod
    def read_env(cls, env_file=None, overwrite=False, **overrides):
        """Read a .env file into os.environ.

        If not given a path to a dotenv path, does filthy magic stack
        backtracking to find the dotenv in the same directory as the file that
        called read_env.
        ...
```

Directory with your module has no `.env` file and `read_env` cannot import it.

You can just import all your `.env` variables in `settings.py` as [suggested](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start) in documentation. Then you can import settings in other modules

`settings.py`

```
import os
import environ

# Initialise environment variables
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

`module.py`

```
from settings import SECRET_KEY

print(SECRET_KEY)
...
```